# $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ region with ball $\overline{D(a, r)} \subset O$, $f$ analytic on $O$ s.t. $|f|$ constant on $\partial D(a, r)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $O \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a region containing the closure of a ball $B := D(a, r)$. Assume $f$ is analytic on $O$ with $|f|$ constant on $\partial B$. Show that $f$ has a zero in $B$.

I feel like the Argument Principle is useful here, but I'm not sure how to use it. I can assume $f$ has no zero in $B$ and conclude that $f'/f$ is analytic on $B$. We have $\int_{\partial B} f'/f = 0$ by Argument Princ. and really by the fact that $f'/f$ is analytic.

The other option is max modulus principle, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What if $|f|=0$ on the boundary? What if $|f|>0$? Try both cases.

Comment: Where is the maximum of $|\frac{1}{f}|$ achieved if $f$ has no zero in B?

Comment: Or this one: [Analytic $f$ with $|f|$ constant on $\partial D$, I need to show that it has at least one $0$ inside $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379944/analytic-f-with-f-constant-on-partial-d-i-need-to-show-that-it-has-atl?rq=1)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks Martin I was looking for a duplicate but couldn't find one. I'll close the question.